# How to make a post button in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, button, hyperlink, get, sinatra

I'm building a small application in Sinatra and need to include a simple button to make a get request which will redirect the user to another page.  I've been using forms for this sort of thing, which seems like overkill.  Here's an example:

```
<form method="get" action="/users/:user_id"> // User id taken on the backend from the session.
  <input type="submit" value="User Profile">
</form>
```

That's a lot of markup for a simple get request.  I can't seem to find any alternatives however.  Is there a way to work a get such as this into a button or anchor tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using form and button, just do this:

```
<a href="/users/:user_id" class="btn">User Profile</a>
```

and style it CSS so that it looks like a button, for example:

```
a.btn {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```